# FFMPEG - concatenation of a dynamic number of files with different codecs

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a bash-script for FFMPEG that concatenates a **dynamic** number of video-files with different codecs.

This is what i have right now: The script basically does the job and concatenates 3 videos.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

But as mentioned i would like to write a script which can process a **dynamic** number of video-files.

For this purpose i have created a text file that contains all the source-material.

```
file './lib/intro.mp4'
file './temp/1.mp4'
file './temp/2.mp4'
file './temp/3.mp4'
file './lib/outro.mp4'
```

I know that i can easily pass a text-file to the `-i` parameter. The problem is that it the `-filter_complex`-parameter is not **dynamic**. The number of files is fixed here.

```
ffmpeg -i files.txt \
    -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \ 
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4
```

Is it possible to modify the script to concatenate a dynamic amount of video-files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the good method to do that (with random file number) is to generate the command before running it ; and with this method you can add some error protection ;) before running the command so it is a good  point. Also that method avoid using a text file list.